# How to add html checkbox in ajax html editor

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax

I have tried to add an HTML checkbox in Ajax HTML editor in ASP.NET, but I am unable to check and unchecked it. This is the code which I tried. Please give some suggestions.

**webform.aspx**

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"     
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
    TagPrefix="cc3" %>
<cc3:Editor ID="uwNotes" runat="server" Width="800px" Height="800px">           
</cc3:Editor>
```

**webform.aspx.cs**

```
decodedtext="";

 decodedtext = decodedtext.Append("<p><b>PLEP: </b><input type=\"CheckBox\"                     
 id=\"checkbox1\" enabled=\"true\">YES</p>");

 uwNotes.Content = decodedtext;
```

Comment: if you're inserting the checkbox into an _editor_, surely the purpose of the editor is to _edit_ the content (including the checkbox), not to _interact_ with it? So I wouldn't expect to be able to check/uncheck it in that context. Once the content entered into the editor is displayed (presumably on some other page), then it should be checkable. Unless I have misunderstood.

Comment: But i got an requirement from client to add the html checkbox inside ajax html editor inside web form. But in preview mode i am able to check/uncheck it.

Comment: what is the purpose of the checkbox? Is it part of the editor functionality, or part of the content of the page being edited?

Comment: Its the content of the page being edited . The user need to check / uncheck it in design mode .

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check box by using the flowing syntax

```
<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"Y\"  style=\"height:auto\" ">
```

Comment: I tried this code . But its not working.Can you suggest some other solution.

Comment: i  have added another answer see it

Comment: Actually , after 3 continuous click the checkbox get checked/unchecked for <input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"Y\"  style=\"height:auto\" ">

Comment: i have given another answer also see it bro

Comment: with the snippet run the snippet ,if it is not the your required answer show where you are getting problem

Answer (score 0):

```
var editor;  // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

$(document).ready(function() {
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    "ajax": "../File Path",
    "table": "#example",
    "fields": [ {
            label:     "Active:",
            name:      "active",
            type:      "checkbox",
         options:   [ { label: '', value: 1 }]
             ]} );
```

Comment: put on one function render : <input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"Y\" >

Answer (score 0):

```
function(render){
  render :<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"Y\">
 }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Actually this code works good in google chrome not in IE. In IE after 3 continous click the checkbox get checked in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

```js
        var response = { optionA: 'One', optionB: 'Two', optionC: 'Three' };

               // this would go in your ajax success handler
                   $.each(response, function (key, value) {var li = $('<li><input type="checkbox" name="' + key + '" id="' +         key + '"/>' +
                 '<label for="' + key + '"></label></li>');
                 li.find('label').text(value);
                    $('#wkslist').append(li);
                       });
```

```css
#wkslist {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="wkslist"></ul>
```

```
               #wkslist {
       list-style-type: none;
             padding: 0;
                  }

             <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
           </script>
           <ul id="wkslist"></ul>
```

Comment: run this in your snippet

Comment: this is the snippet you required

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of your question:

```js
var response = { optionA: 'One', optionB: 'Two', optionC: 'Three' };
$('#json').val('response[i]');
$("button").click(function(){  
$('<p><input type="checkbox"/><span>Response Text</span></p>').insertAfter("li");  
    });
```

```css
#wkslist {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.respons{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  border:1px solid #600;
  color:green;
}
button{margin-top:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="respons">
<ul id="wkslist">
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
<button id="res">Response</button>
```